# How to convert URLs containing Unicode characters into clickable links?

Tags: php, regex, url

I use this function to make URLs to clickable links but the problem is that when there is some Unicode character in the URL it becomes clickable links only before that character...

Function:

```
function clickable($text) {
    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
                          '<a class="und" href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
                          '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})',
                          '<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text);

return $text;

}
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Try replacing your hardcoded `a-zA-Z` with character classes, `:digit:`, `:alpha:` and `:lower:` and `:upper:` and so forth?

Comment: *(sidenote)* The [POSIX Regex functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php) have been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Consider using the [PCRE family](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `eregi_replace`. I don't think it's possible to use it with unicode - and it's depreciated from php 5.3. Use `preg_replace`.

Then you can try something like that

```
preg_replace("/(https?|ftps?|mailto):\/\/([-\w\p{L}\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\p{L}\/_\.#]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/u", '<a href="$0">$0</a>
```

EDIT - updated expression to include # character

Comment: One problem, it breaks when there is # symbol in url! How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using \p{L} instead of a-zA-Z and \p{Ll} instead of a-z

You can find details of unicode handling in regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

And get in the habit of using the preg functions rather than the deprecated ereg functions